# fade in and out background-image css

Tags: html, css

i'm new to this website... anyway, i wonder if it is possible to fade in and out one image into another one automatically at a certain amount of time like for example every 30 seconds? I'm a student and I have to make a project with some guys about a car show and my task is to make the website of the presentation which i did with simple html and css and when it came to the background image I took an image from the net with some cars (2472x1156 pixels) modified it and put it on my background-image css property... the problem is that i want that image to change at a certain amount of time into another image (same size in pixels) but i don't want to put it into a container because if I do so, I would be forced to rearrange everything in the page because as it is normal when a client views my page the computer zooms the page to all the container's size and i don't want that... is this possible to do with jquery or javascript or something like that? I mean a script that affects the css background-image property maybe?!? if it's hard to workaround forget about it because it's not a big deal anyway...
and btw, sorry for my english guys...

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

http://www.techerator.com/2010/11/how-to-make-a-css-background-slideshow-with-jquery/

Comment: i managed to solve my problem but still i found another one:
this is the code:

<script type="text/javascript">
var total1 = function() {
 $("body").attr("class","total1");
 $(".total1").fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
};
var total2 = function() {
 $("body").attr("class","total2");
 $(".total2").fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
};
 $(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
      total1();
}, 5000);
 });
</script>

when i load the page it only show me total1(); and if I try to put total2(); under total1(); then it only recognizez total2();

Comment: How should I do in order for the computer to "play" total1(); then total2(); in a continuous loop at a certain interval?